# Python numpy easier syntax?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am new to numpy, and I'm already a little sick of its syntax.

Something which could be written like this in Octave/matlab

```
1/(2*m) * (X * theta - y)' * (X*theta -y)
```

Becomes this in numpy

```
np.true_divide(((X.dot(theta)-y).transpose()).dot((X.dot(theta)-y)),2*m)
```

This is much harder for me to write and debug. Is there any better way to write matrix operations like above so as to make life easier?

Comment: Unlike Java, you can overload operators in Python. Not familiar about numpy in particular, but maybe you can extend the data type you're working with and inject operator overloading methods to it.

Comment: Unrelated to the syntax issues, it's probably worth computing `X*theta - y` separately and using the value twice instead of recomputing it.

Comment: @user2357112 yes. good point.

Comment: FWIW: In contrast to matlab, `numpy`  is just a package in a general use programming language. So it's no surprise that its syntax is not as "mathematical" as matlab...

Comment: @Santa: numpy already does overload operators to allow elementwise operations, but it doesn't provide an operator for matrix multiplication, basically because there aren't enough operators to go around.  (`*` has to mean either elementwise multiplication or matrix multiplication, and for numpy arrays they decided to make it mean the former.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make some simplifications.  By using `from __future__ import division` at the beginning of your program, all division will automatically be "true" division, so you won't need to use `true_divide`.  (In Python 3 you don't even need to do this, since true division is automatically the default.)  Also, you can use `.T` instead of `.transpose()`.  Your code then becomes

```
1/(2*m) * ((X.dot(theta) - y).T).dot((X.dot(theta) - y))
```

which is a bit better.

In Python 3.5, a new matrix multiplication operator `@` is being added for basically this exact reason.  This is not out yet, but when it is (and when numpy is updated to make use of it), your code will become very similar to the Octave version:

```
1/(2*m) * (X@theta - y).T @ (X@theta - y)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way, but you will have to consult the numpy documentation to find it.

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) lists a bunch of equivalencies between matlab and numpy with simpler syntax. For example, `a.transpose()` can be written as `a.T`.

You can also look at the individual documentation for these functions, such as the one for [`true_divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html) which explains that the Python 3 `/` method works to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `np.matrix` instead of `np.ndarray` for 2-dimensional arrays. It overloads the `*` operator so that it means matrix multiplication, so you can do away with all the `.dot`s. [Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) are the docs.